# Does identifiability of the graph of SEM imply faithfulness to that graph?

Tags: statistics, causality

### Background

Let us consider a Structural Equation Model (SEM): $$X_j:=f_j(\mathbf{PA}_j,N_j), ~ j=1,\ldots,p,$$ where $\mathbf{PA}_j$ are the parents of $X_j$ and $N_1,\ldots,N_d$ are jointly independent noise variables.

The graph $G$ of the SEM is obtained by creating a vertex for each $X_j$ and drawing edges from $\mathbf{PA}_j$ to $X_j, j=1,\ldots,p$.

I read that under the assumption of faithfulness, $G$ can be identified upto its Markov Equivalence Class from the distribution of the SEM. [Lemma 7.2 in Elements of Causal Inference by Jonas Peter et al.]

### Question

Is the converse true? Specifically, assuming that $G$ is identifiable from the distribution of the SEM, then is it faithful to $G$?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

If the faithfulness assumption is not met, there is perfect cancellation between some paths ending in some node, say, $X_t$. The presence of the final edges of the cancelling paths pointing to $X_t$ leave no trace in the joint probability distribution of the graph. There is thus no way to identify the correct MEC from the joint probability distribution since we cannot distinguish between a given graph and a graph with additional edges that cancel out. (In other words, faithfulness is a necessary condition for identifiability.)